# A Text Area That Resembles Multiple Inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to make create a textarea using HTML and CSS where each row looks like a separate input? I have a client that wants this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>My Text Area</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" style="resize:none;">
        This is to be the first row of the text area and the text entered in here should continue to the second row, if I specified the number of rows, for example three rows, then the text area will look like three diffrent inputs
    </textarea>
</div>
```

...to look like this:

[image]

NB: We don't need to dynamically add new rows. The last row will be the limit.

Comment: This is simply impossible with pure HTML + CSS, so you'll need to get your hands dirty with JS.

Comment: Did anyone ask the client _why_ they want to do this? It defeats the whole purpose of having a text _area_.

Comment: I guess you could try and _emulate_ the look, if you gave the textarea content enough line height, and a repeating background image that provides those rounded rectangles ... Getting the background to match font size/line height might be the biggest challenge then, but using SVG this could probably be made somewhat "dynamic".

Answer (score 0):

Kind of...

This isn't a perfect answer because it's not going to look like the example image unless you use SVGs to create the faux inputs (maybe someone can improve this answer), but it may help.

You can change the number of lines by changing the height of the textarea. That said, what happens when there is too much text, for example when the width doesn't accommodate the whole line?

I just want to say this really is a bad idea. If it's absolutely required, JavaScript would be a more reliable option.

```css
textarea {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
  line-height: 2em;
  background-color: #e5e5f7;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-image:  linear-gradient(black 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to right, black 1px, white 1px);
  background-size: 100% 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>My Text Area</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" style="resize:none;">This is to be the first row of the text area and the text entered in here should continue to the second row, if I specified the number of rows, for example three rows, then the text area will look like three diffrent inputs
    </textarea>
</div>
```